# Show Quadratic Discriminant Analysis (QDA) implies a logistic regression model

Tags: machine-learning, classification, discriminant-analysis

I am attempting to show that QDA implies a logistic regression model of the form $\log(\frac{P(Y=1 \mid X = x)}{1-P(Y=1 \mid X = x)}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x + \beta_2x^2$, where there is only one covariate x

Let $P(Y=1 \mid X = x) = p_1(x) = \frac{\cfrac{\pi_1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_1}}exp(\cfrac{-(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2})}{\sum_{l=1}^{K} \pi_l \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_1}}exp(\cfrac{-(x-\mu_l)^2}{2\sigma_1^2})}$

Then,
$\frac{p_1(x)}{1-p_1(x)} = \frac{\cfrac{\pi_1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_1}}exp(\cfrac{-(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2})}{ \sum_{l=1}^{K} \pi_l \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_1}}exp(\cfrac{-(x-\mu_l)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}) -\cfrac{\pi_1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_1}}exp(\cfrac{-(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2})}$

Taking the log of the equation above, I can deduce the numerator to be:
$\log(\pi_1)-\log(\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_1}) -\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}$

But, I do not know how to continue further. I am unsure as to how to take the log of the denominator, and make the terms simplify, so that I can yield the aforementioned quadratic form.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, I am able to get that part. But how do I go about taking the log of the denominator and simplifying those terms?

Comment: Sorry, I mistook what you were seeking.